# Is the product of the Heavens Mystery revelation "Coat of Many Stars" a valid target for Magic Vestment?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

From Magic Vestment:

> Target: armor or shield touched
>
> ...
>
> You imbue a suit of armor or a shield with an enhancement bonus of +1 per four caster levels (maximum +5 at 20th level).
>
> An outfit of regular clothing counts as armor that grants no AC bonus for the purpose of this spell.

It would appear that Magic Vestment can target three things:

1. Something that qualifies as "armor."
2. Something that qualifies as "a shield."
3. Something that qualifies as "an outfit of regular clothing" via an exception.

Coat of Many Stars reads as follows:

> Coat of Many Stars (Su): You conjure a coat of starry radiance that
> grants you a +4 armor bonus. At 7th level, and every four levels
> thereafter, this bonus increases by +2. At 13th level, this armor
> grants you DR 5/slashing. You can use this coat for 1 hour per day per
> oracle level. The duration does not need to be consecutive; it can
> instead be spent in 1-hour increments.

The question is threefold:

1. Based on the first line about conjuring a coat, does the revelation create an actual "coat" or is this just fluff text using the word "coat" to describe the field of radiance?
2. If a coat is created, does it qualify as "an outfit of regular clothing" for the purposes of Magic Vestment despite being a supernatural conjuration with several special properties?
3. If not, does the use of the term "armor" in the 13th level clause qualify the coat as "armor" or "a suit of armor" for Magic Vestment?

Comment: How often does it come up that your character is wearing a Coat of Many Stars and *nothing else*?

Comment: Number 2 is definitely false for any reasonable definition of "regular"...

Answer (score 12):

1) It is a coat. The line "You can use this coat" covers that for me.
2) and 3) Its possible that it falls in between, but see below.

- [Common terms](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Bonus-Armor) states:

  > Bonus (Armor)
  >
  > An armor bonus applies to Armor Class and is granted by armor or by a spell or **magical effect that mimics armor**. {snip}
- [Heavens](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/oracle/mysteries/paizo---oracle-mysteries/heavens) Coat of Many Stars states:

  > Coat of Many Stars (Su): You conjure a coat of starry radiance that grants you a +4 armor bonus.
- [Conjuration](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Conjuration) Creation (which is just for completenes, since the effect isn't called out as any specific school) states:

  > Creation: a creation spell manipulates matter to create an object or creature in the place the spellcaster designates.

From this we can determine that you are in fact wearing an item of clothing, its not just shiny lights, it is in fact an *object* (though don't ask me how you sunder it), and furthermore, it is specifically called out as clothing (coat).

[Magic Vestment](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/m/magic-vestment) states:

> An outfit of **regular** clothing counts as armor that grants no AC bonus for the purpose of this spell.

I would argue that "regular" in this case means "not armor", rather than "commonplace". I'm pretty sure it was not intended to a silken shirt could not have magic vestment cast upon it.

Now, either the coat is armor (because it provides an armor bonus) or it is not (and is therefore clothing). Either way the spell works.

Note: A really stingy DM could argue that clothing doesn't have an AC bonus and therefore the second part of this doesn't apply, in which case your stuck with your DMs interpretation. However, since the spell goes out of its way to basically say "armor or just whatever your wearing" I think the fact that is intended that it should include special cases that fall in between. Point out that Oracles can normally wear armor anyway, and that Mage Armor, Magic Vestment and normal clothing would work.

( All **emphasis** mine )

Comment: *Targeting what you're wearing* would get you two different, non-stacking sources of Armor bonus.

Comment: Things don't need to be armor to grant you Armor bonuses and *a magica effect that mimics armor" is, by definition, not an armor. Claudius Maximus's reference to the 13th level property explicitly calling it armor works better to me.

Comment: @Zachiel, _Magic Vestment_ gives you an **enhancement** bonus, so this will stack with the **armor** bonus of the CoMS.

Comment: @rojomoke No, *Magic Vestement* would give *your dress* an Enhancment bonus to their starting Armor bonus of +0, effectively giving you two items with a positive armor bonus. To have them add up you'd need to cast the Vestment spell on the effect giving you the Armor bonus, to increase it thanks to the Enhancement bonus.

Comment: @Zachiel - An *Enhancement* bonus to AC is not the same as increasing the *Armor* bonus itself - and these two different bonuses do stack with each other. See [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Bonus-Enhancement) - This is not the same as Mage Armor not stacking with regular armor, or not benefiting from wearing two suits of armor at the same time...

Comment: @G0BLiN Quoting from your link: "[...] enhancement bonuses to armor or natural armor effectively increase the armor or natural armor's bonus to AC"

Comment: @Zachiel is right. You have to enchant the thing that grants the armor bonus. Amended my answer.

Answer (score 10):

> Coat of Many Stars (Su): You conjure a coat of starry radiance that grants you a +4 armor bonus. At 7th level, and every four levels thereafter, this bonus increases by +2. At 13th level, **this armor** grants you DR 5/slashing. You can use this coat for 1 hour per day per oracle level. The duration does not need to be consecutive; it can instead be spent in 1-hour increments.

(**emphasis** mine)

It’s an armor. *Magic vestment* may affect it.

Answer (score 2):

**The rules are murky, but I'd rule it's not a valid target.**

- A coat can be either a dress or something covering you, like a coat of paint, so I won't say the Coat of Many Stars qualifies as a vestment.
- Even if that was the case, I won't consider it an outfit of *regular clothing*. Regular does not necessarily mean mundane (for instance, it would be ok to cast Magic Vestment on a *+1 Vest of Resistance*) but I get it as meaning "something made of mundane matter".
- I strongly suspect "armor" is used as a descriptive word to identify a source of protection enveloping you and has nothing to do with the game keyword. I'd have sorted such a detail explicitly (e.g. "it counts as an armor") and way earlier in the description.

While this is all speculation and I'm not taking into account game balance for my decision, I think every single of the elements we have doubts upon slightly tips in the "not a valid target" direction.

Comment: +1 for the second point. Further, I'd emphasize that while a magically created robe is in no way regular clothing, it's also, in game terms, *not* an [outfit](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/goods-and-services/containers-bags-boxes-more).