# Does an Enhancement bonus on clothing become an Armor bonus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic, armor-class

Given this discussion I had [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48015) about combining Magic Vestment and Coat of Many Stars:

> *Targeting what you're wearing* would get you two different, non-stacking sources of Armor bonus. –  Zachiel

> Things don't need to be armor to grant you Armor bonuses and "a magical effect that mimics armor" is, by definition, not an armor. [...] –  Zachiel

> @Zachiel, *Magic Vestment* gives you an **enhancement** bonus, so this will stack with the **armor** bonus of the CoMS. –  rojomoke

> @rojomoke No, *Magic Vestement* would give *your dress* an Enhancment bonus to their starting Armor bonus of +0, effectively giving you two items with a positive armor bonus. To have them add up you'd need to cast the Vestment spell on the effect giving you the Armor bonus, to increase it thanks to the Enhancement bonus. –  Zachiel

Does an Enhancement bonus turn into an Armor bonus if applied to an article that isn't armor?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## This is one of the most annoying and awkward pieces of 3.*x* rules

#### You don’t get enhancement bonuses to AC, you get enhancement bonuses to armor bonuses

So, armors grant an **armor** bonus to AC. Seems simple enough.

Then we have **enhancement** bonuses. You could, in theory, have an enhancement bonus to AC;  if you did, it would stack with an armor bonus, since they are different bonuses. However, as far as I know, there is no effect in the system that gives a creature an enhancement bonus to AC.

No, instead enhancement bonuses are applied to items. When you wear magically-enhanced armor, you don’t have an enhancement bonus, the armor has an enhancement bonus – to the armor bonus that it gives you. So in short, your AC doesn’t “see” an enhancement bonus at all; it just sees a (larger) armor bonus.

A similar example exists in the *amulet of natural armor*’s “enhancement bonus to your natural armor bonus.” This time, the enhancement is on the person wearing the amulet, but it’s not an enhancement bonus to his AC, but an enhancement bonus to his natural armor bonus. As far as the wearer’s AC is concerned, it sees no enhancement bonus, just a larger natural armor bonus.

And so it is with *magic vestment*: it applies an enhancement bonus to an item’s armor bonus (including an armor bonus of +0 from a non-armor). Your AC still only sees a larger armor bonus, not any enhancement bonus.

Thus you might have a shirt that has a base armor bonus of +0, to which it receives a +4 enhancement bonus. The wearer of that shirt gets a +4 armor bonus. If they are already wearing full-plate, the +8 armor bonus of that supersedes the +4 armor bonus of the shirt, so the shirt becomes pointless. On the other hand, *magic vestment* could be cast on the full-plate, giving *it* a +4 enhancement bonus, improving its armor bonus to +12. If it had instead been a *+1 full-plate*, the +4 enhancement bonus would supersede, not stack with, the +1 enhancement bonus, so the armor bonus to the wearer’s AC would still be +12.

Comment: Can you add some support from the Pathfinder RAW to the notion that Enhancement bonus is not a separate bonus type (like Deflection, Dodge etc.)?

Comment: @G0BLiN It *is* a separate type of bonus; you are misunderstanding what’s going on. It’s not that the enhancement bonus type has some magical special property that converts it into armor bonus. This is an issue of what it is a bonus *to* – that is, it’s **not** a bonus *to AC*, it’s a bonus to *an armor bonus*. The armor bonus is to AC, but that’s not relevant. Yes, a bonus to a bonus; ridiculous, but it is what it is.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, now I better understand what you meant (and it makes more sense than the way I understood it before...). Still, can you please point me to some citations or examples in the RAW which show that this is how Enhancement bonuses work (i.e. it's not a bonus to some attribute, it's a "bonus to a bonus")?

Comment: @Goblin [PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Enhancement-Bonus), plus the wording of the bonus, plus the ability to use a magic shield and magic armor at the same time.

Comment: @Goblin There's a 3.5 [Rules of the Game](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20040127a) that discusses this.

Comment: @AceCalhoon - not trying to be contrary here, but - the link's wording seems almost the same as those for Deflection or Luck bonuses, which modify a trait and not "the bonus to a trait". The magic shield and armor should stack just as the same effect can give different Morale bonuses (one for attack roles, and one for saves) - "shield" and "armor" can be viewed as different attributes affecting AC. And...

Comment: ... Finally, take the wording quoted below for Magic Vestment for example: "You imbue a suit of armor or a shield *with an enhancement bonus of +1* [...]" - that seems to treat enhancement as a standard brand of bonus. I'll grant that the wording of Barkskin seem to support KYran's point though ("[...] grants a +2 enhancement bonus to the creature's existing natural armor bonus") - I'm not sure how Pathfinder handles this...

Comment: @starwed - and now I'm really confused - the linked discussion just states that Enhancement bonuses to armor, shield or natural armor don't apply to touch attacks since they "improve a specific aspect of the character's defenses." - but that's just like the way a Luck bonus to attack with a mundane masterwork sword won't make it any better against an incorporeal creature - it doesn't mean the Luck bonus is "a bonus to the attack bonus" of the sword, it just "improve an aspect of the character's attack" like any other attack modifier...

Comment: @G0BLiN: I think you're skipping over this relevant text: "WhereEnhancement Bonuses Apply: In general, an enhancement bonus goes with a **specific item a character uses**, or with one of the user's abilities or other statistics."

Comment: @Goblin The rules are not worded great, but this part is pretty clear: *"Since enhancement bonuses to armor or natural armor effectively increase the armor or natural armor's bonus to AC..."* -- Enhancement bonuses increase the bonus to AC.

Comment: @Ellesedil, thanks, but still, that's how most other bonuses work as well - if a character gains a Profane bonus to dexterity, whenever she is denied her dex bonus, that Profane bonus won't apply. Same goes if it was a Moral, Luck, or Circumstance bonus to dex... I'll reread this article tomorrow and see if I can find what I'm missing - still not convinced it applies to PF as well, but at least it discuss the issue in detail...

Comment: @KRyan can you please cite in the book where your enhancement bonus becomes part of the armor bonus. I think you bring a valid point but I would like to see where the book says this.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus If you are still questioning enhancement bonuses and how they affect armor and/or shields, I recommend you take a look at this answer.