# Magic Vestment on Bracers of Armor?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, magic-items

The Bracers of Armor are described to "surround the wearer with invisible but tangible field of force", which essentially is an invisible suit of armor.

My question is: **Can *Magic Vestment* be cast on this "invisible but tangible field of force"?**

The idea is to make a Cleric that runs around foes to trigger their opportunity attacks, so that his allies can move around more freely. He'll be wearing the Bracers, an Animated Shield, and a Monk's Belt, with Magic Vestment on the Bracers and the shield.

---

I apologize for not clarifying the scenario because I was so intent on the primary question. Here is a bigger picture:

- I am sort of a powergamer/munchkin that is rolling with a casual group; my Cloistered Cleric is too powerful for the rest of the group. This is why I'm toning it way down and trying to not steal the Paladin's and the Barbarian's thunder (instead opting to boom up their thunder). I also don't think the DM is quite aware of my power level relative to the group; I guess I just RP the goofy cleric that well. :)
- The *Monk's Belt* + *Animated Shield* combo is a non-issue with the DM; he's ruled that the Animated Shield does not interfere with *anything* except carrying another shield. As such, he's given me the green light to stack the two.
- Relevant equipment are traveler's clothes, Bracers of Armor +4, Animated Shield, and Monk's Belt (he's a generous DM). The Human is Cloistered Cleric 5/Dweomerkeeper 2/Divine Disciple 2 and his current stats are Str 10, Dex 14, Con 18, Int 12, Wis 20, Cha 18 (like I said, a generous DM, even with the point-buy).
- The question of Magic Vestment on the Bracers only arose in our last game session (because we were forced into a gauntlet scenario, and the Barbarian's AC is pitiful, the Paladin's is alright, but not optimal), and he ruled OK on it off-hand, although he seemed unsure. I just wanted a clarification so that he at least gets some peace of mind. I don't really mind if the general consensus or RAW is advantageous to me or not; our game is fun enough for me to not really be concerned about a couple of points to AC. ^_^

Comment: Note that you can't benefit from monk's belt and shield, animated or not.

Comment: Ah! *Cloistered* Cleric, this certainly changes your options since you are limited to *Light Armor* (as neither *Dweormkeeper* nor *Divine Disciple* add armor proficiency).

Answer (score 3):

**Bracers, no. Shield, yes.**

---

The description states, as you have pointed out:

> **They** surround the wearer with an invisible but tangible field of force...

(emphasis: **bold**) The bracers *themselves* emanate this invisible tangible field of force and would have to be the target of any other special effect.

[Magic Vestment](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicVestment.htm), for a target, states:

> Target: Armor or shield touched

There is no "suit of armor" - just a "force field."

---

The shield, however, would be fine as a target.

**Note:** An [animated](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicArmor.htm#animated) shield would already have an enhancement bonus<sup>1</sup> (since its cost is a +2 bonus), and your spell would merely over-right, or if your caster level isn't high enough, or have no effect on the enhancement bonus the shield already has.

---

<sup>1</sup>[Magic Armor](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicArmor.htm#): A suit of armor with a special ability must have at least a +1 [enhancement](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#enhancementBonus) bonus.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: revised with the OP's classes and stats in mind; oh, and the house rule on allowing the Animated Shield for a monk which considerably changes things.*

**No**, *Magic Vestment* cannot be applied on the *Bracers of Armor*.

The simplest way to get a good Armor Class is to wear an Armor (and wield a Shield), and spells such as *Magic Vestment* build on this, restricting their improvements to Armor (or clothes) and Shield.

There are classes that allow adding your Wisdom bonus to AC (in place or on top of your Dexterity bonus), however for a full caster the synergy would be poor.

The generic way is to use:

- A good armor, a *Mithral Chain Shirt* costs 1,100 gp and grants +4 AC/+6 Max Dex/0 ACP, you can go one step further with a *Mithral Breastplate* thought it costs 4,200 gp for only +1 AC at +5 AC/+5 Max Dex/-2 ACP. I would personally opt for the *Chain Shirt* because 3,100gp for just +1 Armor AC (and -2 ACP to boot!) is costly.
- An *Animated Heavy Shield +1* gives you a +3 Shield bonus to AC.
- Some *Gloves of Dexterity +4* for 16,000 gp give you +4 to Dexterity, which translates to +2 Dexterity bonus to AC.
- You can use *Magic Vestment* on both Armor and Shield, remember that it adds an *Enhancement bonus*, and thus overwrites the existing +X and does not add to it.

With this (simple) basis, you get:

- an Armor bonus to AC of +5
- a Dexterity bonus to AC of +4 (+2 increase)
- a Shield bonus to AC of +3

For a total of +12 AC. As a 9th level Cleric, casting *Magic Vestment* (+2 Enhancement bonus at this level) on both Armor and Shield bumps this to +15 AC.

Let's compare:

- 17,100 gp / +8 AC (compared to running naked) with *Mithral Chain Shirt* (+4) + *Gloves of Dexterity +4* (+2) + *Magical Vestment* (+2)
- 20,200 gp / +9 AC (compared to running naked) with *Mithral Breastplate* (+5) + *Gloves of Dexterity +4* (+2) + *Magical Vestment* (+2).
- 29,000 gp / +9 AC (compared to running naked) with *Bracers of Armor +4* (+4) + *Monk's Belt* (+5)

*Note: I purposely ignore the Animated Shield and its enchantments as your generous DM allows it in both cases.*

While your setup is fun, it is a needlessly costly basis. Starting from the *Mithral Chain Shirt* gives you 11,900 gp to increase your AC.

---

Now that this is done, let's see the bonuses:

- You should start by getting some *Natural Armor*, *Insight*, *Deflection* and *Dodge* bonuses; see http://aaronwiki.us/index.php?title=Armor_Class_Guide for the most cost efficient ways to increase your Armor Class: it suggests that at level 12 you could be looking at +1 Dodge, +2 Deflection, +2 Natural Armor and +1 Insight (for a total of +6 AC)
- The domain *Balance* from *Player's Guide to Faerun, p. 84* has for specific bonus the ability to, once per day, get your Wisdom bonus to AC for 1 round/Cleric level.
- The feat *Expeditious Dodge* from *Races of the Wild, p. 150* grants +2 Dodge bonus to AC whenever you move 40 ft. or more; it also counts as Dodge for the purpose of fulfilling pre-requisites
- The feat *Mobility* from *Player's Handbook, p. 98* grants +4 Dodge bonus to AC to avoid Attacks of Opportunity when moving (and has Dodge as a pre-requisite). Do remember that Dodge bonuses to AC stack.
- The feat *Protection Devotion* from *Complete Champion, p. 61* grants, once per day, a +2 to +7 Sacred bonus to AC against evil to you and every ally within 30 ft for 1 minute. You can use it one extra time per day for each 3 *Turn or Rebuke* uses that you expend.
- The spell *Barkskin* from *Player's Handbook, p. 203* grants +1 Enhancement bonus to Natural Armor, and +1/3lvls (up to +5), for a total of +4 at level 9, is accessible through the *Plant* domain.
- The spell *Sirine's Grace* from *Spell Compendium, p. 191* grants, among other things, a +4 Enhancement bonus to Charisma and a Deflection bonus to AC equal to your (newly adjusted) Charisma bonus for 1 round/level; it can only be cast by a Bard or Druid and has a target of Personal, however it could be used as a basis for a custom item.

Alright, let's I don't see you changing your domains and feats overnight, however:

- *Amulet of Natural Armor*, 2,000 gp, +1 Natural Armor bonus to AC
- *Ring of Protection*, 2,000 gp, +1 Deflection bonus to AC
- *Ioun Stone, Dusty Rose*, 5,000 gp, +1 Insight bonus to AC (very costly, not included below)

That is, for 4,000 gp, you can get +2 AC.

- 21,100 gp / +9 AC (compared to running naked) starting from *Mithral Chain Shirt*
- 24,200 gp / +10 AC (compared to running naked) starting from *Mithral Breastplate*

Those are, of course, the permanent items; you can also use temporary buffs (items, spells, potions, ...) to have a higher spike AC if it still matters.

However, let's check the total AC:

- 26 AC with *Mithral Chain Shirt* and the bonuses
- 27 AC with *Mithral Breastplate* and the bonuses (3,100 gp more expensive, and -2 ACP)
- 25 AC with *Bracers of Armor* (7,900 gp more expensive)
- 28 AC with *Bracers of Armor* and the bonuses (16,900 gp more expensive)

This seems like a good permanent AC; at this level the Armor Class guide is only at 29 AC.

---

With that being said, I feel the need to warn you: a character is NEVER obliged in any way to use its Attack of Opportunity on the first opportunity it has. An intelligent character, unless specifically goaded, is thus quite likely to ignore the running fool and keep its sole Attack of Opportunity for a worthy target... or one it feels it has a chance to actually affect.

I thus feel the need to mention that:

- should you optimize your character's AC without optimizing the rest of the party's AC, then your tough character runs the chance of being ignored by mundane foes (who have little chance of affecting it), which is detrimental to the goal you are attempting to achieve
- should you optimize the whole party's AC, then you will force the GM's hand into either looking for heavier hitters or switching strategies, so as to keep your party challenged; after all, with no challenge it would be boring

If your goal is to protect your party, I thus advise you to spend a bit more time selecting disabling spells; it will be more effective.

Comment: You’re ignoring the *monk’s belt* mentioned in the question. A cleric should expect Wisdom to be quite high, so that’s fairly substantial.

Comment: @KRyan: I've thought about speaking about the expected amount of AC but without the character's stats it's quite annoying to go around speculating from thin air so I preferred to cut the answer short and remain factual; giving all the points to the OP. Also, I am unclear on whether one can benefit from the Wisdom bonus to AC from the Monk's Belt and use an Animated Shield (the Armor we know is out of the equation), which makes comparing both course of actions harder, so I just compared costs.

Comment: Magic vestment can be cast on ordinary clothing, as well as armour.

Comment: @GMJoe: The [SRD](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/magicVestment.htm) seems to disagree with you, specifying a **Target:** *Armor or shield touched*. Unless you count ordinary clothing as an armor of AC 0, but then I would argue the character should be counted as wearing Armor which would prevent it from benefiting from its Wisdom to AC.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The spell's description broadens its target: "An outfit of regular clothing counts as armor that grants no AC bonus for the purpose of this spell."

Comment: @HeyICanChan: but in this case, is the character unarmored? I mean, should not the regular clothing count as unarmored or as an armor that grants no AC *both* for the spell and the Monk's restriction at once? It seems inconsistent for it to count as armor for the spell and unarmored to fit the Monk's restriction....

Comment: @MatthieuM. It "counts as armor... for the purpose of this spell," not for anything else. Magic is inconsistent. `:-)`

Comment: @HeyICanChan: Okay, so we are only left with the fact that a shirt with +3 Armor bonus to AC would be useless when wearing Bracers of Armor with a +8 Armor bonus to AC (since the bonuses will not stack). Interesting to know in the absence of bracers, still.

Comment: @KRyan: I altered the answer now that the OP has clarified the *Cloistered* Cleric's classes and attributes, taking into account the (homebrew I think) rule that the Monk's Belt AC bonus still applies when using an Animated Shield. I hope this addresses your concerns. I am unclear on how much of the 20 in Wisdom is already enhanced (or is just a starting 18 + 2 from leveling) so did not include Wisdom boosting in the answer; still, the Bracers of Armor + Monk's Belt are very costly to start with...

Comment: @MatthieuM. So... Are you going to remove the "restricting their improvements to Armor and Shield" bit, since you can benefit from the spell without either?

Comment: @GMJoe: Good point, I added clothes to the list.

Answer (score 1):

> These items appear to be wrist or arm guards. They surround the wearer with an invisible but tangible field of force, granting him an armor bonus of +1 to +8, **just as though he were wearing armor**.

> Target:   **Armor** or shield touched
>
> You imbue a suit of armor or a shield with an **enhancement bonus** of +1 per four caster levels (maximum +5 at 20th level).
>
> **An outfit of regular clothing counts as armor that grants no AC bonus for the purpose of this spell.**

1. This can be implied to work due to the 'just as though he were wearing armour' clause of bracers of armour.  If it works 'just as though wearing armour', there's no reason magic vestment shouldn't work.
2. Even more simply, bracers are themselves part of a suit of armour.  There's not really an argument that they are ineligible as targets for the spell themselves.  If they can't be an eligible target for Magic Vestment, neither can a Breastplate.
3. Finally, 'enhancement bonus to armour' **explicitly stacks** with regular ol' armour bonus.  Casting Magic Vestment on your clothes?  Will stack with bracers of armour.  Bracers of armour do not grant an enhancement bonus to armour.  They grant a normal armour bonus.  Exactly the same as wearing armour.  Just like the Mage Armour spell.  Cast Magic Vestment on your clothes, wear bracers of armour, you get the benefit of both bonuses.

You can safely assume any GM that doesn't allow this is houseruling it rather than using any sort of RAW.

---

**Shields and Armour Class**

You are correct that a Monk's Belt is generally the path to maximum AC.  However, you are incorrect that shields (animated or otherwise) factor in.  An animated shield counts as carrying it - and disables the wisdom-adding effect of the Monk's Belt, as it works 'as a monk', and monks lose their AC bonus if wearing armour or **carrying a shield**.

That's not really a... big issue, though?  Shield, the Sorcerer/Wizard spell, is easily wanded via UMD - it also lasts for minutes/level.  There's also cleric spells that give a shield bonus.  All of that said the absolute largest source of AC is Natural Armour.  Which is granted by Alter Self, Polymorph, and any number of cleric spells (there's one with Tortoise in the name).  Scintillating Scales will turn it into a Deflection bonus, which is largely better.  Various spells will also increase Dex, from the humble Cat's Grace to regular ol' Grace and Divine Agility (or some such) gives a +10.

There's also stuff like Recitation and so forth that give sacred bonuses to things.  Sirine's Grace is a go-to, although somewhat difficult to cast for a cleric (only from scrolls, it's a large reason to play a bard actually).

[Top 10 Divine Persistent Spells (By Level)](http://brilliantgameologists.com/boards/index.php?topic=7543) is a good starting point for buffs, although it's not exhaustive (as there are some good buffs that are not persistable).  Have a read.

You can also stack various stats to AC.  Getting wisdom four or five times to your AC is rather nice.

Comment: My concern here is the Magic Vestment on the clothes while wearing Bracers. That would result in two separate armor bonuses (from enchanted clothes and from the Bracers). Wouldn't that be like wearing armor while wearing the Bracers (and thus be forced to use only the higher bonus, i.e. no stacking allowed)?

Comment: "Finally, 'enhancement bonus to armour' explicitly stacks with regular ol' armour bonus." - This is correct, but the phrasing seems to run on a popular misinterpretation. Enhancement bonuses to armor don't carry over to your AC and then stack with the armor bonus to your AC. The enhancement bonus to armor [directly applies to your armor, and increases its armor bonus to your AC](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/48075/1204). I suggest rephrasing would be helpful to not perpetuate the misinterpretation.

Comment: The enhancement bonus to Armor applied to regular clothes enhances the AC of the clothes, so casting *Magic Vestment* as a Cleric 12 on a shirt would give you a shirt with +3 Armor bonus to AC. The bonus from this shirt would not stack with the bonus from the bracers, however, as they are both Armor bonus to AC. You have to apply *Magic Vestment* to the Bracers for its Enhancement bonus to increase the Armor bonus offered by the Bracers.

Comment: @MatthieuM. - You're incorrect by RAW.  An enhancement bonus to armour class applies to the wearer of any item providing that bonus - it doesn't stack with other enhancement bonuses, but does do so with several other listed bonuses.  The 'clothes' themselves are a worn item - they do not have their own AC, except as modified by size for purposes of a Sunder attempt.  As the spell says to 'treat them as armour with a bonus of +0', they can't even be Sundered - the Sunder rules have an exception for armour.

Comment: @JackLesnie: This is the first time I hear this interpretation, so I am a bit surprised. Reading [**Enhancement Bonus**](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#enhancementBonus) from the SRD I cannot see what would support it; it seems to treat armors and weapons the same way: the enhancement bonus applies to the object itself, not the person/creature. I found [this discussion](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-237026.html) on the topic where opinions go back and forth but which seems to end with "cannot add Bracers & Magic Vestment", do you have any other ruling?